# CTRL + ALT + L and CTRL + ALT + DEL are not working in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: shortcut-keys, lock-screen

I have re installed ubuntu-desktop. After that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> shortcuts are not working.

If I click on the button on the top right side of the desktop (where things like *logout*, *switch user* and *shutdown* appear) I can see that lock screen has <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> next to it, but its colored grey. If I am clicking from there screen lock and logout are working. But the shortcuts are not working.

Comment: Are you using Unity? What is the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screensaver`?

Comment: I am getting the following output:
'<Primary><Alt>l'

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround you could create a shortcut (System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts tab) and assign it to command `gnome-screensaver-command  -l`

Comment: I tried creating custom shortcut as mentioned above. Even then it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 16.04:

**System settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts tab > System** Change *Lock Screen* from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to whatever you want (for example <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).